# Change UART pin

Tags: softwareserial, uart

I am developing GPRS HTTP send request code using a GSM/GPRS module. I found the following code via google:

```
/*************************************************************************
* SIM800 GPRS/HTTP Library
* Distributed under GPL v2.0
* Written by Stanley Huang <stanleyhuangyc@gmail.com>
* For more information, please visit http://arduinodev.com
*************************************************************************/

#include <Arduino.h>

// change this to the pin connect with SIM800 reset pin
#define SIM800_RESET_PIN 7

// change this to the serial UART which SIM800 is attached to
#define SIM_SERIAL Serial


// define DEBUG to one serial UART to enable debug information output
//#define DEBUG Serial

typedef enum {
    HTTP_DISABLED = 0,
    HTTP_READY,
    HTTP_CONNECTING,
    HTTP_READING,
    HTTP_ERROR,
} HTTP_STATES;

typedef struct {
  float lat;
  float lon;
  uint8_t year; /* year past 2000, e.g. 15 for 2015 */
  uint8_t month;
  uint8_t day;
  uint8_t hour;
  uint8_t minute;
  uint8_t second;
} GSM_LOCATION;

class CGPRS_SIM800 {
public:
    CGPRS_SIM800():httpState(HTTP_DISABLED) {}
    // initialize the module
    bool init();
    // setup network
    byte setup(const char* apn);
    // get network operator name
    bool getOperatorName();
    // check for incoming SMS
    bool checkSMS();
    // get signal quality level (in dB)
    int getSignalQuality();
    // get GSM location and network time
    bool getLocation(GSM_LOCATION* loc);
    // initialize HTTP connection
    bool httpInit();
    // terminate HTTP connection
    void httpUninit();
    // connect to HTTP server
    bool httpConnect(const char* url, const char* args = 0);
    // check if HTTP connection is established
    // return 0 for in progress, 1 for success, 2 for error
    byte httpIsConnected();
    // read data from HTTP connection
    void httpRead();
    // check if HTTP connection is established
    // return 0 for in progress, -1 for error, bytes of http payload on success
    int httpIsRead();
    // send AT command and check for expected response
    byte sendCommand(const char* cmd, unsigned int timeout = 2000, const char* expected = 0);
    // send AT command and check for two possible responses
    byte sendCommand(const char* cmd, const char* expected1, const char* expected2, unsigned int timeout = 2000);
    // toggle low-power mode
    bool sleep(bool enabled)
    {
      return sendCommand(enabled ? "AT+CFUN=0" : "AT+CFUN=1");
    }
    // check if there is available serial data
    bool available()
    {
      return SIM_SERIAL.available(); 
    }
    char buffer[256];
    byte httpState;
private:
    byte checkbuffer(const char* expected1, const char* expected2 = 0, unsigned int timeout = 2000);
    void purgeSerial();
    byte m_bytesRecv;
    uint32_t m_checkTimer;
};
```

The problem is I have no idea how to change or define Rx and Tx Pin. If I define SIM_SERIAL serial1 it's showing me error. I want to change it to pins 10 and 11.

Here is other code whenever I try to compile it shows me error on "serial1" online. above code is sim800.h file

here is program code of send data through http

```
"SIM800.h"

#define APN "connect"
#define con Serial
static const char* url = "http://arduinodev.com/datetime.php";

CGPRS_SIM800 gprs;
uint32_t count = 0;
uint32_t errors = 0;

void setup()
{
  con.begin(9600);
  while (!con);

  con.println("SIM800 TEST");

  for (;;) {
    con.print("Resetting...");
    while (!gprs.init()) {
      con.write('.');
    }
    con.println("OK");

    con.print("Setting up network...");
    byte ret = gprs.setup(APN);
    if (ret == 0)
      break;
    con.print("Error code:");
    con.println(ret);
    con.println(gprs.buffer);
  }
  con.println("OK");
  delay(3000);  

  if (gprs.getOperatorName()) {
    con.print("Operator:");
    con.println(gprs.buffer);
  }
  int ret = gprs.getSignalQuality();
  if (ret) {
     con.print("Signal:");
     con.print(ret);
     con.println("dB");
  }
  for (;;) {
    if (gprs.httpInit()) break;
    con.println(gprs.buffer);
    gprs.httpUninit();
    delay(1000);
  }
  delay(3000);
}

void loop()
{

  char mydata[16];
  sprintf(mydata, "t=%lu", millis());
  con.print("Requesting ");
  con.print(url);
  con.print('?');
  con.println(mydata);
  gprs.httpConnect(url, mydata);
  count++;
  while (gprs.httpIsConnected() == 0) {
    // can do something here while waiting
    con.write('.');
    for (byte n = 0; n < 25 && !gprs.available(); n++) {
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  if (gprs.httpState == HTTP_ERROR) {
    con.println("Connect error");
    errors++;
    delay(3000);
    return; 
  }
  con.println();
  gprs.httpRead();
  int ret;
  while ((ret = gprs.httpIsRead()) == 0) {
    // can do something here while waiting
  }
  if (gprs.httpState == HTTP_ERROR) {
    con.println("Read error");
    errors++;
    delay(3000);
    return; 
  }

  // now we have received payload
  con.print("[Payload]");
  con.println(gprs.buffer);

  // show position
  GSM_LOCATION loc;
  if (gprs.getLocation(&loc)) {
    con.print("LAT:");
    con.print(loc.lat, 6);
    con.print(" LON:");
    con.print(loc.lon, 6);
    con.print(" TIME:");
    con.print(loc.hour);
    con.print(':');
    con.print(loc.minute);
    con.print(':');
    con.println(loc.second);
  }

  // show stats  
  con.print("Total Requests:");
  con.print(count);
  if (errors) {
    con.print(" Errors:");
    con.print(errors);
  }
  con.println();
}
```

i already know how to send data through http using AT command and software serial library here is  my code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.write("AT\n");
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.write("AT+CSQ\n");
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.write("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"internet\"\n");
  delay(2000);
  mySerial.write("\nAT+SAPBR=1,1\n");
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.write("AT+HTTPINIT\n");
  delay(1000);




}

void loop() { // run over and over
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    delay(1000)
    serial.print(enter key)
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    delay(2000);
     mySerial.write("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://www.mydomain.in/index.php?dt=testdata\"\n");
     delay(2000);
     mySerial.write("AT+HTTPACTION=0\n");
      delay(2000);
      mySerial.write("\n");
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
```

In this code I define Rx Tx (UART)pin. Can you please suggest me any idea how can i define RX Tx pin in sim800.h file. because serial1 give me error on compiling time

Comment: That doesn't look like your code.

Comment: yes i said i found code on google

Comment: How would you possibly expect us to be able to tell you what to change it to without seeing any of your code?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
> ```

Well there you are.

```
#define SIM_SERIAL mySerial
```

Comment: thank you. should i add SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX code in sim800.h file  above #define SIM_SERIAL

Answer (score 0):

I think Serial1 has to do with the Hardware serial Port(tx1,rx1) on Arduino mega . But since you are not using Serial.print i suggest you try "Serial/Serial0" if you are using UNO. 
If you want (10,11) like you said then i think you should use Softwareserial

 #include SoftwareSerial.h //check spelling online not sure
SoftwareSerial allex(10,11);

 #define SIM_SERIAL  allex 

 try it and see if it works.

Comment: should i change #define con Serial also..

Comment: i set default serial port using only serial declaration but default RX and TX pin not working

Comment: I change sim800.h code "#define SIM_SERIAL mySerial" to "#define SIM_SERIAL Serial'